# Diamond-inheritance scenario compiles fine in G++, but produces warnings/errors in VC++/Eclipse

Tags: c++, oop, class, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have a base class 'Base', which is a pure virtual class:

```
class Base {

public:
    virtual void A() = 0;
    virtual void B() = 0;

    virtual ~Base() { } // Eclipse complains that a class with virtual members must have virtual destructor
};
```

I also have 2 other classes, one of them implements A() and the other one implements B():

```
class DerivedA : public virtual Base
{
public:
    virtual void A() {
        printf("Hello from A");
    }
};

class DerivedB : public virtual Base
{
public:
    virtual void B() {
        printf("Hello from B");
    }
};
```

The virtual keyword in the declaration should solve the diamond problem.

Now I would like to combine the two classes into another class, so that both A() and B() are implemented, like this:

```
class DerivedC: public DerivedA, public DerivedB {
     // Now DerivedA and DerivedB are combined
};

// Somewhere else in the code
DerivedC c;
c.A();
c.B();
```

**The problem:**
Even though G++ compiles the code just fine, Eclipse gives an error: `The type 'DerivedC' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'Base::B'`.
When compiling with visual studio, I get 2 warnings:

```
warning C4250: 'DerivedC' : inherits 'DerivedB::DerivedB::B' via dominance
warning C4250: 'DerivedC' : inherits 'DerivedA::DerivedA::A' via dominance
```

**So the question is:** what is the correct way of doing this? Does the code above produce undefined behavior?

**Note:** The title may be a little misleading, I have no idea what a good title for this question would be.

Comment: I have updated the title of your question. While not perfect, it is less generic. Your question could be further improved if you provided a complete code-example that we can copy/paste/compile to reproduce the error (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: @BjörnPollex Thanks, this title is a little better. The original code in which I want to use the concept is way too complex to put in this question, but you could copy and paste the current code if you want to compile. Just add the stdio.h header, and place the 'Somewhere else in the code' part in the main function, and that's it.

Comment: I know that I could easily construct a sample from the code you have provided myself. The idea here is that you are likely to get more help if you make it *as easy as possible* for others to reproduce your error. Another remark: Could you specify the compiler-versions you are using (and also which compiler you Eclipse is using?).

Comment: @BjörnPollex Eclipse version is Juno (the error was generated by the eclipse error checker or however it is called). Note that eclipse compiles using G++. G++ version is 4.7.0 (mingw package), and Visual Studio version is 2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **What is the correct way of doing this? Does the code above produce undefined behavior?**

The code is perfectly valid. There is no Undefined Behavior here.
An unqualified call of `A()` through a `DerivedC` class object, will always call `DerivedA::A()`,    while an unqualified call of `B()` through a `DerivedC` class object, will always call the `DerivedB::B()` instance.

Visual C++ gives you a warning because your code uses a less commonly known feature of virtual Inheritance which may not be obvious to most common users and might surprise them. In this case, the *warning* should be taken as an *Informative Nitpick* rather than a warning.

Note that the C++ Standard does not restrict compilers from emitting informative warnings for perfectly valid code. 
The documentation for [warning C4250](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b3sy7ae%28VS.80%29.aspx) gives an example which tells you why visual C++ chooses to give this warning.

Comment: I understand, however the warnings are there for a reason, maybe there could be a scenario where this would cause a conflict. For example, if DerivedA or DerivedB implemented both functions, this could cause some trouble.

Comment: The formal specification of dominance may not be widely known, but the results are what one would intuitively expect.  It's the basis for the widely used mixin technique.  The warning is totally stupid.  (But Visual Studios allows turning warnings off on a one by one basis, so you can just turn this one off.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I wouldn't go as far as saying the warning being *"totally stupid"*. For some fairly experienced users the warning may seem that way but for novice programmers it could be fairly useful, especially since the documentation explains *"why?"* in much detail.And since the warning can be easily suppressed by using the [warning pragma.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @Als The information is OK, but "warning" seems to imply more.  The formal semantics of C++ result in what one would intuitively expect, and it doesn't seem very sensible to "warn" that you're getting what you would intuitively expect.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try this :

```
class DerivedC: public DerivedA, public DerivedB {
public:
    using DerivedA::A;
    using DerivedB::B;
};
```

I can't test with Eclipse or VC++ myself...

Comment: In Visual Studio it gives the same warnings, but in Eclipse/G++ the error seems to be gone.

Comment: You probably want one of those, but not both of them.

Comment: @Mehrdad: They are different functions, so it should be fine to declare `using` for both.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why a compiler would complain about any of this; this is
just the standard mixin technique.  Classes `Base`, `DerivedA` and
`DerivedB` are abstract, and can't be instantiated, but that's usually
the case for mixins.  The whole point of a mixin is that it doesn't
implement all of the interface.  And `DerivedC` implements both `A()`
and `B()` through its inherited members.

If a compiler refuses to compile this code, it is broken.

As for warnings... a compiler is free to warn about anything it pleases:

- There is no requirement that a class with virtual members have a
  virtual destructor.  In practice, it's usually a good idea, however
  (unless the destructor is protected), and a compiler warning is
  appropriate.
- The warnings from Visual Studio are "informative", I guess, but this
  is the way the language is designed to work.  And it's certainly not
  something to avoid.  For that matter, I don't think that dominance
  actually plays a role here, since the functions in `Base` are pure
  virtual.  What Visual Studios seems to be trying to say is that in
  `DerivedC`, the actual overload of `A()` is `DerivedA::A()`, and not
  `Base::A()`.  Which seems to be what one would intuitively expect to me;
  the rules concerning dominance are really just a formal statement of
  what one would intuitively expect.

Anyway, I'd definitely turn the warning about dominance off.  There's
certainly nothing to worry about in that respect.  And I'd complain
loudly about a compiler which didn't compile the code.

Comment: Both the compilers compiled the code, VS just gave warnings, and the eclipse error was generated by the eclipse automated error checker or something, but the actual compilation in eclipse is done using g++.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio is known to have a [compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/101259/) issuing warning C4250 in situations where the dominated function is pure virtual.  The bug has been closed as "Won't fix"; the accepted solution is to suppress the warning using:

```
#pragma warning( disable: 4250 ) /* 'class1' : inherits 'class2::member' via dominance */
```

See also discussion at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b3sy7ae(VS.80).aspx#CommunityContentHeader.

Answer (score 0):

Your Base class is abstract : it can't be instantiated.
The B and A class are also abstract because they implement only one method.

The two solutions are, in file `DerivedC.cpp`

```
void DerivedC::A(){ 
   DerivedA::A();
}
void DerivedC::B(){
   Derived:B();
}
```

Or you can use `using` keyword in your header-file:

```
class DerivedC: public DerivedA, public DerivedB {
public:
    using DerivedA::A;
    using DerivedB::B;
};
```

Comment: In the first case, if I call `A()` will it also call the inherited version, or only the `DerviedC::A()` which is empty? Shouldn't you call `DerivedA::A()` inside `DerviedC::A()`?

Comment: Okay I understand, you should also do a little spellcheck, it's 'Derived' instead of 'Dervied'.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary (unless `DerivedC` defined other `A()`).

Comment: In fact it can be necessary because DerivedC is a DerivedA so if one function or method just need a DerivedA you can give it a DerivedC. As DerivedA::A and DerviedA::B are virtual (and pure virtual for ::B) if the function calls the B method it will call DerivedC::B. So you got to define the behaviour of DerivedC::B as a call to DerivedB::B by writing it or by using `using` keyword.